# Installing Hydra image from a Docker Hub repository gives error: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server, hydra

I am trying to pull a hydra image using the following shell script. This script is supposed to pull the image from a docker repository and then configure it based on the needs of the server:

```
echo "Getting Hydra image from hub.docker.com"
docker pull linuxserver/hydra
echo "-----------------"

echo "Importing Hydra database..."
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint hydra linuxserver/hydra migrate sql $DATABASE_URL_HYDRA
echo "-----------------"
```

However, when I run this script, I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"hydra\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Comment: Is this an image you're building, and if so, can you add the `Dockerfile` to the question?  Or are you just trying to run some prebuilt image?

Comment: I am trying to run a prebuilt image. It's oryd/hydra